# How to compare mean values in mostly un-paired opinion surveys

Tags: mean, missing-data

I have 2 groups of participants A and B in an opinion survey. Participants A give an opinion on a group of "objects" X and participants give an opinion on a group of "objects" Y. Opinions are values on a scale 1 to 5. (I have all scores, but can not do additional surveys)

The mean values (opinion scores) for X and Y are very similar. But most participants in A don't know Y, and most participants in B don't know X -- i.e. most can not compare X and Y, but only objects withing group X or group Y.

But there is a small overlap in participants A and B. Those participants score some objects from both X and Y, and suddenly there is a large difference between mean values if a take scores only from the overlapping participants. The problem is that this is a small overlap of participants and a small portion of the objects that is being scored.

Still, this leads me to believe that the (main) reason that the mean values from both surveys are similar is because the participants have no comparison between the groups.

I know something about basic statistics, but not enough to argue/proove that the similarity in mean values in not valid argument that groups X and Y are of similar quality.

I would need to do an appropriate analysis to give a more objective comparison of X and Y.

I need some pointers on literature where I would find established statistical methods to make a more valid comparison for this situation or at least to argue that comparing mean values with un-paired participants is not valid. Maybe just the correct English terms would help, so I can search further on my own (English is not my native language and in school we only learned our terms in our language).

Comment: As a first step, I would make graphs with data from the people who have rated both X and Y. But I'd be very concerned about the apparent difference in mean between the people who overlap and those who don't. Data that is Missing Not At Random (which seems very likely based on what you've stated) can be very difficult and sometimes impossible to draw reliable inferences from.

Comment: You may find some useful threads tagged [tag:missing-data]